# How to click on a button and be sent to another view with the item id of the item where the button was. Laravel - vue.js - inertia-vue

Tags: html

I'm making a dashboard that has discussion forums and the user has to answer them, what I want it to add a button to the card that has the discussion forum info and that opens the view where the user can add a comment. But to be able to answer the correct forum I need to send the forum id that the user clicked on.

I've tried with `inertia-link` and with a @click button.
This is the routes I have

```
Route::resource('comments', 'ReplyController', ['except' => ['index']]);
Route::get('comments/{id}', 'ReplyController@index');
```

In the controller

```
public function index($id)
{
    $forum = DiscussionForum::where('id', $id)
        ->with('comment', 'user')->first();
    $comment = ForumReply::with('discussionForum', 'user')
        ->where('discussion_forum_id', $forum->id)
        ->orderByDesc('comment_time')->get();

    return Inertia::render('Forum/Comment.vue', [
        'forum' => $forum,
        'comments' => $comment
    ]);
}
```

This is what I've tried, this takes me to the page, but it's blank and it shouldn't be

```
<a class="el-button el-button--warning"
:href="'comments/' + f.id"> Contestar </a>
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: where is the html of the button you're gonna click ? it's not server side issue, it's client side. a link `<a href="/comments/{id_of_the_comment}" />` would do the trick....

Comment: @N69S I added more info